CORS error when trying to upload via presigned url from browser, but not in non-browser environment
I'm trying to generate s3 presigned url to upload video/mp4 files to a bucket from react app client in development mode in my localhost. However, I'm getting CORS error. But when I do the put request from a python script it goes through, which establishes that my presigned url is working. What I found odd though, the whole thing starts working after a few hours without any changes to the setup, so basically after the bucket is a few hours old. I mean the presigned url stops giving cors error.
This is how I'm generating presigned url:
import os
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError
import uuid
import json

def handler(event, context):
    bucket_name = os.environ['BUCKET_NAME']
    object_name = str(uuid.uuid4())+ ".mp4"
    aws_region = "eu-west-1"
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name=aws_region)


    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('put_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                            'Key': object_name,
                                                            'ContentType': 'video/mp4'
                                                            },
                                                    ExpiresIn=3600,
                                                    HttpMethod='PUT',
                                                    )
    except NoCredentialsError:
        return {
            'statusCode': 400,
            'body': 'No AWS credentials found'
        }

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps({
            'upload_url': response,
            'object_name': object_name
        })
    }

This is my how my client react app is making the request:
onst uploadFile = async (file: File) => {
        setUploading(true);
        setUploadSuccess(null);

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);

        try {
            // gets the presigned URL for uploading the file via lambda function url
            const uploadUrl: string = await axios
                .get(
                    "https://somethingsomething.lambda-url.eu-west-1.on.aws/",
                )
                .then((response) => response.data.upload_url);


            // uploads the file to the presigned URL
            const response = await axios.put(uploadUrl, file, {
                headers: {
                    "content-type": file.type,
                },
            });
            
            if (response.status === 200) {
                setUploadSuccess(true);
            } else {
                setError("Upload failed. Please try again.");
                setUploadSuccess(false);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setError("Upload failed. Please try again.");
            console.error(error);
            setUploadSuccess(false);
        } finally {
            setUploading(false);
        }
    };

This is the CORS configuration on the S3 bucket:

Error in Chrome console:

Preflight option request and response header:

Error in Firefox console:

Network tab in Firefox:

Python code that uploads without any issue:
import requests

def upload_file_to_s3(file_path, presigned_url):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        try:
            response = requests.put(presigned_url, data=file)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                print("File uploaded successfully.")
            else:
                print(f"Failed to upload file. Status code: {response.status_code}")
                print(response.text)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = 'file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4'  
    presigned_url = "MANUALLY_COPY_PASTED_URL"
    upload_file_to_s3(file_path, presigned_url)


I found the solution here:
S3 presigned URL works 90 minutes after bucket creation
import os
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError
import uuid
import json
from botocore.client import Config


def handler(event, context):
    region = "eu-west-1"
    bucket_name = os.environ['BUCKET_NAME']
    object_name = str(uuid.uuid4())+ ".mp4"
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'), region_name=region,
                             endpoint_url=('https://s3.'+ region + '.amazonaws.com'))


    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='put_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                            'Key': object_name,
                                                            'ContentType': 'video/mp4' },
                                                    ExpiresIn=3600,
                                                    HttpMethod='PUT',
                                                    )
    except NoCredentialsError:
        return {
            'statusCode': 400,
            'body': 'No AWS credentials found'
        }

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps({
            'upload_url': response,
            'object_name': object_name
        })
    }


